# Firebase firestore permission denied when execute get data from react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvbJD.png)

I used the firestore API to get data from FireBase. But encountered the error as above. I checked the read and write data on Cloud FireStore and found that read permission was allowed but I don't know why it still can't be done. Please help me. thank you so much.

This is my sample code:
[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElXUc.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you should use catch method, to avoid unhandled promise error. So

```
.then(() => {}).catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

second if you got permission error, then you should set your firestore rules correctly. If you are in development state then i suggest set values true like this:

```
allow read, write : true;
```